# Integrating Firebase with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase

I am trying to create an Authorisation scene using Unity and Firebase. A screenshot of my C# script along with the error shown is attached here. Is there a separate directory that needs to be specified for integrating Firebase. I went through the documentation provided in this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/unity/password-auth.
I have done all the steps. Please go through it, and tell me what I'm missing!

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SignUp : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public GameObject list;
 public Text email;
 public Text password;
 public GameObject logIn;
 Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
 private string userID;
 private string pass;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
  //Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth auth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {
  auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync (userID, pass).ContinueWith (task => {
   if (!task.IsCanceled && !task.IsFaulted)
    Debug.Log ("User Created");
   else
    Debug.Log ("User Creation Failed");
  });
 }

 public void signUp ()
 {
  list.SetActive (true);
  logIn.SetActive (false);
 }

 public void details ()
 {
  userID = email.text.ToString ();
  pass = password.text.ToString ();
  print (userID);
  print (pass);
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is your screenshot? And by the way, don't post screenshots, post code directly please.

Comment: I've done it @MichaelFaisst

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: "The type or namespace 'Firebase' could not be found" at line 13

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [quickstart samples](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity) that are provided? There is an example of using the auth in that code.

Comment: @techvice The same error is shown even in the samples provided.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was going wrong. Apparently, Firebase Auth cannot be implemented in Unity Editor. 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/3